# MP3 CD compatibility with older MP3 capable car stereo system

Tags: audio, mp3, stereo

I have MP3 files recorded on CD-R. The files play on a newer (2012) MP3 capable car stereo, but not on an older (2006) MP3 capable car stereo. The following caveat is in the User Manual for the older system. "Due to technical incompatibility, certain recordable and re-recordable compact discs may not function correctly when used in Ford CD players." What is the nature of this known incompatibility and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Really difficult to guess, there's too many details both in the CD structure and MP3 encoding. Do you have some MP3 files on CD that actually work with the 2006 car stereo? Comparing these of those that don't work would make it a lot easier.

Comment: Couple of simple tests - 1) try with no VBR MP3 recordings, use fixed rate only. 2) Double-check the player can use your CDRs at all, using PCM files, AIFs burned as red-book [standard audio CD format] There are a multitude of freeware converters you can use to save to very specific formats for testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many individual factors, but they can be summarized in this:

Technology, even the "same" technology, changes, and eventually you get to a point where older systems have less than perfect compatibility with newer discs.

The way to overcome it is going to be through trial error, finding the disc types and burn modes that work with the older hardware.

One of the first things I would check is to try burning at a lower speed.

Comment: What difference does burning at a lower speed make? Surely the resulting disk is exactly the same format?

Comment: It may be vestigial knowledge now, but in my experience discs burned at slower speeds have a higher rate of compatibility with older systems. It is one factor that is easy (and cheap) to test. I'd heard it had to do with the precision of the reading lasers able to note the possibly less clear divots produced by higher speed writing.

Comment: Whether the suggestion of a lower burning speed is outdated or not, it is still the first and most common advice found on similar questions across the internet, FWIW.

Comment: So I found after some googling :)